# Creating a pie chart with colors and pattern in r

Tags: r, ggplot2, pie-chart

I need to create a pie chart in R, in grey scale (total 7 shades/patterns), but using a pattern for only some of them.

When I try the following

```
ggplot(data = spcomp, aes(x = "", y = percent, fill = NameSp )) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_fill()) +
  geom_text(aes(label = round(percent, digits = 2)), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
  coord_polar(theta = "y") +
  facet_wrap(~ Pach_Type)  +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(),
    axis.title.y = element_blank()) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#000000", "#FFFFFF","#999999", "#FFFFFF", 
                                "#333333", "#666666", "#FFFFFF"))
```

I obtain:

[image]

Now, I would like to include for the Rat a stripe pattern, and for the Vole a dotted pattern. However, when I try to include geom_col_pattern() as follows:

```
ggplot(data = spcomp, aes(x = "", y = percent, fill = NameSp )) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_fill()) +
  geom_col(color = "black") +
  geom_col_pattern()+
  geom_text(aes(label = round(percent, digits = 2)), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
  coord_polar(theta = "y") +
  facet_wrap(~ Pach_Type)  +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(),
    axis.title.y = element_blank()) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#000000", "#FFFFFF","#999999", "#FFFFFF", 
                                "#333333", "#666666", "#FFFFFF")) + 
  scale_pattern_manual(values=c("Abert_Sq" = "none", "Chipmunk" = "none",
                            "Mouse" = "stripe", "Rat" = "stripe", 
                            "Red_Sq" = "none", "Rock_SQ" = "none", "Vole" = "wave"))
```

but I obtain stripes everywhere:

[image]

And if I try to include at the beginning pattern = NameSp I have the following error:

```
ggplot(data = spcomp, aes(x = "", y = percent, fill = NameSp, pattern = NameSp )) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_fill()) +
  geom_col(color = "black") +
  geom_col_pattern()+
  geom_text(aes(label = round(percent, digits = 2)), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
  coord_polar(theta = "y") +
  facet_wrap(~ Pach_Type)  +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(),
    axis.title.y = element_blank()) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#000000", "#FFFFFF","#999999", "#FFFFFF", 
                                "#333333", "#666666", "#FFFFFF")) + 
  scale_pattern_manual(values=c("Abert_Sq" = "none", "Chipmunk" = "none",
                            "Mouse" = "stripe", "Rat" = "stripe", 
                            "Red_Sq" = "none", "Rock_SQ" = "none", "Vole" = "wave"))
```

Error in `geom_col_pattern()`:
! Problem while converting geom to grob.
i Error occurred in the 3rd layer.
Caused by error in `if (pat == "regular_polygon" && is.numeric(params$pattern_shape)) ...`:
! missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Comment: What did you get when you ran `rlang::last_error()`?

Comment: I can't add in the comment all the output, but here is the first part: Error in `geom_col_pattern()`:
! Problem while converting geom to grob.
i Error occurred in the 3rd layer.
Caused by error in `if (pat == "regular_polygon" && is.numeric(params$pattern_shape)) ...`:
! missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
---
Backtrace:
  1. base (local) `<fn>`(x)
  2. ggplot2:::print.ggplot(x)
  4. ggplot2:::ggplot_gtable.ggplot_built(data)
  5. ggplot2:::by_layer(...)

Comment: I think "none" is probably not a valid value, it's looking for a pattern called "none".  Try just not including the ones you don't want or using "".